# Unity3d Silhouette Highlight for 2d sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, sprite

I want to implement `Silhouette Highlight` on `MouseOver` like in this picture:

[image: Example]

Built in Unity3d user interface elements have a component called `Outline` and `Shadow`, but they only work with the user interface, not with the `SpriteRenderer`. The first idea was to create a second sprite with highlight at background and enable it to `MouseOver`, but I think that this method is not good.

Comment: I'd say you think wrong. The method you describe is the easiest one and most appropriate. The other way would be to work on the shader level, you could try a Toon shader.

Comment: Indeed - there's **nothing wrong** with simply making the "glow sprites" and turning them on and off.  That's the AAA approach!  :)  It's true that you could write a shader that does this, but really that would be bad engineering - totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Everts (and me) mentions in a comment,

there's nothing wrong with simply making the "glow sprites" and turning them on and off. That would certainly be done in many large games: it's good.

It's true that you could **write a shader** that does this, but really that would be "bad engineering" - totally unnecessary for such a simple need.  (And to be clear, arguably it's plain better to make custom sprites.)

Now, this brings us to an important point about Unity engineering -

## it's critical to use existing assets, in Unity work.

There are a couple of stand-out examples.  Like, NatCam and Edy's vehicle system. You just - literally - cannot use the camera in a game unless you use "NatCam"; the only alternative would be to completely pointlessly spend a year building NatCam yourself.

In this case, there are many good "glow shaders" available ...

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/20166

Enjoy!

[image]